# Using powershell to change multiple file names

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there any way for me to change multiple file names? here is an example;

file names;

file1_R1

file2_R2

file3_R3

All i want to be able to do is delete the _R(num)

so the end result would be;

file1

file2

file3

and a brief explanation of the code would be much appreciated.

This is the code I have tried so far but unable to do it successfully with wild cards;

```
 get-childitem *.pdf | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_R1", "") }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes this is entirely possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have a look at the [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item), specifically example 4.

Comment: This is what I have tried but im having trouble with wild cards;

get-childitem *.pdf | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("-Model", "") }

Comment: Please add this code to your question by editing it. Reading code in comments sucks.

Comment: edited thank you for the tip!

Comment: Well, for one thing your file names do not have -Model in them.